# Ping host address's return value

Tags: c#

I want to ping any ip address and get the return value which shalt let me know whether it was successful or not. Something like that

```
if(ping.Equals(success)) { ... }
```

Comment: So then what is your question?  What research have you done before posting this here?  In fact, what effort, if any, *have* you put into this?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hb7xxkfx(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: what s `ping.Equals` BTW?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var sender = new Ping();
var result = sender.Send("127.0.0.1");
if (Result.Status == IPStatus.Success)
    // OK
else
    // it failed
```

Please note that you will need to add this using directive: `System.Net.NetworkInformation`

Comment: @downvoter why don't you state any reasons? It matched the op's question.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but some people do object to people answering low effort questions on principle. An upvoted answer will also prevent the question from being auto-deleted after it's closed.

Comment: @MattBurland thank you for letting me know. I just wanted to help.

Answer (score 1):

[First result on google for "C# Ping".](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx) Examples near the bottom of the page.

But basically boils down to

```
Ping pingSender = new Ping ();
PingReply reply = pingSender.Send (ip, timeout);
if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
     //Success
else
     //Failure
```

Comment: Thanks! Why did Jan use var and you didn't? Any advantages?

Comment: Both are functionally equivalent and will produce the same output code. My way is simply more verbose, but both ways are valid. var means the compiler will interpret the type for you, without needing to specify. Comes in handy when dealing with generics.